# Using R forecast package in Docker Plumber

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, plumber

I am trying to build a docker image for a R-script which is using the forecast library. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
    FROM r-base:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/myscripts
COPY ./Plumber.R /usr/local/src/myscripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/myscripts

RUN R -e 'install.packages("plumber")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("forecast")'

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)"]
CMD ["Plumber.R"]
```

The Plumber.R is very simple and contains in the first line library(forecast). 
Without forecast everything works nicely and I can run the container. When adding forecast in the dockerfile as above and in Plumber.R the execution of the container stops with:

> During startup - Warning messages:
>   1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>     there is no package called ‘forecast’
>   2: package ‘forecast’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
>   pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
>   Error in library(forecast) : there is no package called ‘forecast’
>   Calls:  ...  -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In readLines(file) : incomplete final line found on 'Plumber.R'
>   Execution halted

Any idea what is the issue? With all other packages/libraries it works only forecast is making trouble. 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I build a container using your Docker file, I get some messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘TTR’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘quantmod’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘tseries’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

The root of these messages is the following error:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So running `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` before installing the R packages should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks that´s leading in the right direction, I got it now working with `RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  git-core \
  libssl-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev` That was as well there in the original Tresletech Plumber Docker image. I just didn´t know what it is good for. All other packages are working fine without these lines of code except `forecast`.

Comment: @Sebs030 From my experience it is quite normal that you have to install some `*-dev` packages in order to to install packages from CRAN. One alternative is to use binary packages, c.f. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/12/22/#014_finding_binary_deb_packages.